# Is it possible for a phone to save video directly to PC hard drive?

Tags: camera, video, video-recording

I want to use my phone as a camera, but at the same time not to use any recording software on the PC, because it drains a lot of processor speed and has lag.

As in to use a directory on the PC hard drive as the main save and temp directory.

I haven't seen any discussion on this topic so i was wondering if it were possible, if it is it would be highly useful.

Comment: What phone do you have? It's hard to say that what one phone can do is possible on another phone. Software version, model number and any other relevant info would be helpful.